# Преобразование числа 42956.4160069444 в формат даты в пределах 2010-2018

Tags: python, дата

В базе содержится дата в виде - 42956.4160069444. Необходимо преобразовать в вид число.месяц.год.
time.ctime не помог, выдаёт:

> 'Thu Jan  1 21:55:56 1970'

PS:Год должен получится в пределе 2010-2018

Comment: Какой странный формат, это timestamp? Попробуйте через `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`

Comment: Без знания точки отсчёта это может оказаться какая угодно дата

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Число слишком маленькое, чтобы число секунд представлять с известных эпох, потому будем считать, что на входе число дней.

По значению число близко к [Dublin Julian Date (DJD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Variants):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime as DT

djd = DT.timedelta(42956.4160069444)
dublin_epoch = DT.datetime(1899, 12, 31, 12)
dt = dublin_epoch + djd
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))  # -> 2017-08-10
```

Подобное представление можно встретить в астрономических задачах, к примеру, [PyEphem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/) использует это представление:

```
>>> import ephem   # $ pip install ephem
>>> str(ephem.Date(42956.4160069444))
'2017/8/10 21:59:03'
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
import time
t = 42956.4160069444
t = time.ctime(t)
ts = time.strptime(t)
ts_f = time.strftime("%d %b %Y", ts)
print(ts_f)
```

вывод:  >>> 01 Jan 1970

Comment: или если изменить формат: ts_f = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y", ts) , то результат: 01.01.1970

Answer (score 0):

```
    >>> import datetime

    >>> seconds = (42956.4160069444 - 25569) * 86400.0
    >>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds)

    datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 9, 59, 2, 999996)
```